# Почему extends не работает?

Tags: java, ооп, конструктор

Ругается ошибкой на `extends`, по книжке всё должно работать. В чём проблема?

**ОШИБКА:**

> Error:(37, 1) java: constructor Person in class com.company.Person cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Person Papich = new Person("Vitaliy");

        Papich.display();

    }
}
```

```
class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void display() {

        System.out.printf("Name : %s", name);
    }
}
```

```
class rabotyaga extends Person {

    private String Zavod;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас конструктор с параметром в суперклассе. Поэтому, когда вы расширяете класс, то должны создать конструктор, который будет вызывать конструктор суперкласса с параметром.

```
class rabotyaga extends Person {

   private String Zavod;

   public rabotyaga(String name){
      super(name);
   }

}
```

Comment: Угу, действительно. Дзякую!