# Если в классе создаю конструктор - не могу наследовать класс, что можно сделать?

Tags: java, ооп, классы, наследование, extend

```
class Salad{

    private int numIngridients;

    public Salad(int numIngridients){
        this.numIngridients = numIngridients;
    }

    public String[][] salatik(){
        String[][] salaticOK = new String[numIngridients][3];

        return salaticOK;
    }
}

class Calories extends Salad {

}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
java: constructor Salad in class Salad cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

При наведении на второй класс, в котором хочу наследовать первый - пишет

```
There is no default constructor available in 'Salad'
```

Как можно наследовать класс в таком случае?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке

> Error: java: constructor Salad in class Salad cannot be applied to given types; required: int found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

гласит что у Вас отсутствует конструктор по умолчанию в классе, от которого вы пытаетесь унаследоваться

Конструктор по умолчанию это конструктор без аргументов, он подразумевается для классов, у которых в листинге нет ни одного конструктора и его нет у классов с уже объявленным конструктором с аргументами

```
public Salad(){}
```

Вот так должен выглядеть класс:

```
class Salad {

    private int numIngridients;

    public Salad(){}

    public Salad(int numIngridients){
        this.numIngridients = numIngridients;
    }

    public String[][] salatik(){
        String[][] salaticOK = new String[numIngridients][3];
        return salaticOK;
    }
}
```

Еще наследование возможно, если вы явно наследнике укажете один из существующих конструкторов, который будет вызван при конструировании наследника:

```
class Calories extends Salad {
    public Calories (int numIngridients){
        super(numIngridients);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`There is no default constructor available in 'Salad'`.

Нет конструктора по умолчанию в классе Salad, так создайте его.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, как это сделать

Comment: и разве

public Salad(int numIngridients){
        this.numIngridients = numIngridients;
    }

не является конструктором?

Comment: Сделать это просто (в принципе выше об это уже написано) `public Salad(){}`. Да это конструктор с параметром, однако наследуемый класс по умолчанию должен создаваться точно с таким же конструктором с параметром, но для текущих реалий - в наследуемом классе требуется создание объекта конструктором без параметров (конструктор по умолчанию), а поскольку его нет, то и выдается ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no default constructor available in 'Salad' "

Если нет конструктора по умолчанию в суперклассе, а есть в подклассе, то можно создать конструктор без аргументов в суперклассе (если этого сделать нельзя, то см. далее). Без этого невозможно создать экземпляр подкласса, так как **конструктор по умолчанию является конструктором без аргументов** (обратное неверно) и он будет неявно вызывать такой же конструктор суперкласса при создании экземпляра подкласса. И если в подклассе есть какой-нибудь конструктор, то конструктор по умолчанию не существует.

Для создания экземпляра подкласса требуется последовательно вызывать конструкторы суперклассов, поэтому если какой нибудь из конструкторов отсутствует, то его надо создавать явно. Если в суперклассе есть конструктор с аргументами, следовательно отсутствует конструктор по умолчанию, и в подклассе нужно создавать такой же конструктор, который вызывает конструктор суперкласса и передаёт ему аргументы. Для этого в первой строке конструктора подкласса надо вызывать конструктор суперкласса следующим образом

```
super(*args*);
```

Что-то наподобие того как в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889788/204920) ответе.

Здесь *не важно* какой конструктор  и сколько у него аргументов, главное чтобы вызывался конструктор суперкласса при создании подкласса.

Если в подклассе есть конструктор без аргументов, то он будет вызываться неявно из конструктора по умолчанию, но в данном случае такого конструктора нет, и по этой причине возникает ошибка.