# Как поля иницилизируются дефолтными значениями?

Tags: java, ооп, инициализация, field

Готовлюсь к OCA. Попался на такой вопрос.

```
 package abc;
 class Fruit{
     int seeds;
     String taste;
     boolean edible;
 }

 class TropicalFruit extends Fruit{
     double weight;
     TropicalFruit(){
         seeds = 0;
         taste = "sweet";
         weight = 10.0;
     }
 }

 class Banana extends TropicalFruit{
    double calories;
     Banana(){
         seeds = 10;
         weight = 20.0;
         calories = 200;
     }
 }

 public class TestClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Banana b = new Banana();
         System.out.println(b.edible+" "+b.weight+" "+b.calories);
     }
 }
```

Какой конструктор иницилизирует поле класса `Fruit` `edible`?

Логично, что поле `edible` по умолчанию `false`.

Подумал, что наверное в классе `Object` при создании объекта что-то происходит и ответил, что в конструкторе `Object`'а, но ответ не правильный.

Comment: @nikoshi Ответ неверный.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a
> reasonable default by the compiler.

То есть компилятором.

Comment: Это относится только к переменным примитивного типа, потому что переменные объектного типа ничего не содержат, т.е значение равно `null`.

Comment: Для непримитивов `null` и есть `reasonable default`

Answer (score 0):

> Подумал, что наверное в классе Object при создании объекта что-то происходит и ответил, что в конструкторе Object'а, но ответ не правильный.

Коннчно неправильный, потому что у класса всегда есть конструктор. Только он может быть задан неявно. Даже если в классе нет конструктора, то Java компилятор создаёт *конструктор по умолчанию*.

Что такое конструктор по умолчанию можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957278/204920).

> конструктор по умолчанию является конструктором без аргументов (обратное неверно)

Чтобы ответить на вопрос, нужно посмотреть в каком конструкторе идёт *присваивание* переменной.

И обнаруживается, что в ни каком. Поэтому переменная остаётся не инициализирована. И поскольку она примитивного типа, то принимает значение при создании переменной. То есть булевая переменная по умолчанию `false`.

Comment: @nikoshi Я не понял твоего вопроса.

Comment: @nikoshi В этом ответе я написал что в ни каком.