# Наследование полей java

Tags: java, наследование

Совсем запутался, помогите.

Есть общий класс Pet

```
public class Pet {

    String name;

}
```

Есть его наследник класс Cat

```
public class Cat extends Pet {

    private int age;

    public Cat(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

И я вообще не понимаю, как создать объект класса Cat с именем и возрастом.

Так выдаёт ошибку

```
 Pet cat = new Cat("Имя кота", 12);
```

Подобный конструктор - не понимает что значит слово super

```
 public Cat(String name, int age) {
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему extends не работает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889782/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-extends-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 6):

Дело в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к конструктору, которого нет у класса родителя. Для этого необходимо в родителе прописать соответствующий конструктор, сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
public class Pet {

public Pet(String name) {
    this.name = name
}

String name;

}
```

Таким образом, конструктор класса Cat сможет обратиться к конструктору класса Pet, так как в данном случае этот конструктор стал существовать

Comment: Спасибо оромное!

Answer (score 3):

***Вариант 1***

Добавить соответствующий конструктор в родительский класс (`Pet`):

```
public class Pet {
    String name;

    public Pet(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

В паре с вызовом вашего "подобного конструктора" у класса наследника (`Cat`):

```
    public Cat(String name, int age) {
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
    }
```

---

***Вариант 2***

Явно проинициализировать поле родительского класса (`Pet`) в конструкторе класса наследника (`Cat`):

```
    public Cat(String name, int age) {
        super.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

При этом не создавая никаких конструкторов в родительством классе (`Pet`).

Если классы находятся в разных package, то полю `name` в классе `Pet` необходимо будет добавить модификатор доступа `protected` (или выше), чтобы оно было доступно в наследнике.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте модификатор `protected` для поля `name` у класса `Pet`:

```java
public class Pet {
    protected String name;
}
```

Тогда у наследников будет доступен `this.name` и конструктор можно будет написать так:

```java
public Cat(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```